# Australian teen show about the planet jupiter 90s

Tags: tv, space, story-identification

I've been wondering for a while about a TV show that aired in Australia, I believe it was Australian made, that featured some teenagers on a spaceship either going to or coming back from Jupiter. My mind has gone fuzzy on the details, but it might have involved some of Jupiter's moons.
Any help exposing the name of the show would be much appreciated! I thoroughly enjoyed it as a kid and hope to perhaps rewatch it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["Escape from Jupiter"](http://youtu.be/4sQvZYLyXE4)

From Wikipedia:

> Escape from Jupiter is an Australian children's science fiction drama which aired from 10 April 1994 to 3 July 1994. Concerning a small group of children on Jupiter's moon Io, the series ran for 13 episodes.
>
> When one of Io's volcanoes erupts, the surviving colonists must flee the moon and try to reach the safety of Earth. Finding a derelict station in orbit of Jupiter, they convert it into a rudimentary space craft and set off, having many adventures and forming close relationships along the way.
>
> The series was followed by Return to Jupiter.