# Sci Fi story - mining colony with robots?

Tags: story-identification, books

My memory of this story is extremely vague. I don't think I ever read/listened to the whole story either. I would have had it as a child in maybe 1995-6. What I do remember is that it was both a book and a cassette, and the book has illustrations.

If I remember right it was quite serious and a bit dark. It was set on a different planet and there were large robots or machines. I can't remember if they were autonomous or if the people in the (possibly a mining?) colony controlled them. Part of the plot involved swarms of small creatures (maybe robots too?) that could eat metal.

The art was quite epic if I remember right, and the cassette had sound effects and acting as opposed to just being read out.

Comment: Can you recall whether it was part of a series or set in a particular "universe"? I mean for example might it have been part of the [Mortal Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Engines) series, or a *Doctor Who* audio book, or ...?

Comment: Sorry I really can't remember anymore, it was definitely on a different planet, they maybe lived in caves? Underground facilities? The book had full colour illustrations if I remember correct in quite a detailed classic sci fi style. I don't think it was part of another universe or anything.

Comment: Well, it's not a lot to go on. If you can remember *anything* else at all - maybe the publisher, names of any of the characters, and so on, that would help! Based on what you've provided, there's a *tiny* chance it's one of:

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82503/80s-young-adult-science-fiction-book-with-cassette

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/australian-teen-show-about-the-planet-jupiter-90s

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My mistake it was a short story by Anatoly Denprov, not Isaac Asimov.

Page 13 of Die Insel der Krebse
(The island of crabs)*

"It is difficult to describe what followed. Several machines fell...trying to get hold of a scrap of metal...striving to get into the middle.
Within a few minutes the place where he had thrown the metal had
become the arena of a terrible battle, which more and more robots came
running to join."

*one translation

Comment: Can you add a quote from Runaround involving the swarms of small creatures that eat metal mentioned in the question? Also, Powell and Donovan were not robots.

Comment: There are no swarms of metal-eating robots in this story.

Comment: (Re: edit) Not set on a different planet or mining colony https://archive.org/details/AnatolyDneprovCrabsOnTheIsland/page/n19/mode/1up but does have the robots